# The "add_rostest" macro is not being recognized

Tags: catkin, rostest, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create my rostests for catkin, and I've been following the instructions here: [www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild).

My CMakelists.txt file includes these two lines:

```
add_executable(guiTest EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL src/test/guiTest.cpp)
add_rostest(test/guiTest.test)
```

However, upon running catkin_make, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at au_uav_ros/CMakeLists.txt:81 (add_rostest):
  Unknown CMake command "add_rostest".
```

Why isn't it recognizing add_rostest?  My "rospack list" command shows that I have: rostest /opt/ros/groovy/share/rostest.  Should I just try re-installing the rostest package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65423/the-%22add_rostest%22-macro-is-not-being-recognized./) by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer had to do with linking libraries.  I had to add:

```
target_link_libraries(guiTest ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

to my CMakesList, and then the test node was found.  I don't remember this step being mentioned though for the original rosbuild rostests.

---

Originally posted by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) with karma: 195 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need this in your `package.xml`:

```
<build_depend>rostest</build_depend>
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt` add it to your catkin components:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rostest ...)
```

**Update**: regarding your next problem, `target_link_libraries()` is [required for nearly *every* catkin build target](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/building_executables.html#building).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on 2013-06-18**:
Thank you.  I followed your suggestions, but once the package does compile, the [au_uav_ros/guiTest] node is not found (or does not exist).

I'm thinking that I have to use:
set_target_properties(guiTest PROPERTIES ...)
since the migration page says to use this.  What would the proper args be?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-18**:
That sounds like a separate question. I doubt it's target properties, but we'll probably need to see (most of) your `CMakerLists.txt` to figure it out.